# How can I check what data type of variables of dataframe in one time?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe object 'df' which have a lot of columns(variables). These variables have different data type, for example:

```
>>> df.thal.head()
0    6.0
1    3.0
2    7.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
Name: thal, dtype: object
```

Obviously, 'thal' variable data type is object. I can use

```
df.thal.astype(float)
```

to change its data type. But i have a great many variables and i can't check them one by one.

Is there some ways check all of variables data type and then change their data type in one time?

Thanks.

Comment: `df.dtypes` will let you check all the columns at the same time